# Reset button and bootstrap validation on Option change in select

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-select

I have select with options. On option change i show different divs and use bootstrap validator before submit. If input is empty and press on button it goes to disable. And on option change button is not activating. How can I reset inputs and button on option change?

```js
$('#shexsselect').on('change', function() {
  value = $(this).val();
  if (value == 1) {
    //do something
  } else {
    //do something
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form_fin').bootstrapValidator({
    message: 'This value is not valid',
    feedbackIcons: {
      valid: 'glyphicon',
      invalid: 'glyphicon',
      validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
      pinofsv: {
        message: 'The username is not valid',
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'for label 2'
          },
        }
      },
      shexsselect: {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'choose'
          }
        }
      },
      voen: {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'for label2'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form name="form_fin" id="form_fin" action="" method="POST">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group" id="shexsdiv">
      <label>Selectionn: </label>
      <select class="form-control " name="shexsselect" id="shexsselect" required>
        <option value='' selected disabled>Choose</option>
        <option value='1'>First</option>
        <option value='2'>Second</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="voendiv">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>label2:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control " name="voen" id="voen">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="fin_input">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Label2:</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pinofsv" id="pinofsv" required />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="checkfin" id="checkfin">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I tried `excluded: [':disabled'],` but it did not help and by jquery tried to reset and clear, but doesn not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `onchange` inside your `select` and there you call your function to reset values of input fields.

Below is working code:

```js
function resetFields() {
  document.getElementById("voen").value = "";
  document.getElementById("pinofsv").value ="";
}
```

```html
<form name="form_fin" id="form_fin" action="" method="POST">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group" id="shexsdiv">
      <label>Selectionn: </label>
      <select onchange="resetFields()" class="form-control " name="shexsselect" id="shexsselect" required>
        <option value='' selected disabled>Choose</option>
        <option value='1'>First</option>
        <option value='2'>Second</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="voendiv">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>label2:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control " name="voen" id="voen">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="fin_input">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Label2:</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pinofsv" id="pinofsv" required />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="checkfin" id="checkfin">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Read [**here**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) more about onchange event

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes it is reset input value, but not activating button and does not hide validation text( which does bootstrap validation ).

Comment: @Orik00 that was not in the requirement. This answer is fulfilling your requirement that you mentioned in your question.

Comment: main problem is reset button, reset input is simple, anyway thank you for your reply)